# Get data from websocket server to create Gantt chart in Angular

Tags: angular, websocket, server, get, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a gantt chart in angular. I am using syncfusion gantt chart which takes 3 data arrays in app.component.ts. The data must be taken from a text file which is red and converted to json object in a server file. I am using websocket in this case. My problem is that I use the ws.onmessage = function(evt) method to get data from server, I don't know how to render this data so that I can use it in the gantt chart. That is to say, this function doesn't return anything. This data is stored in the variable ressource as mentionned in the component.ts code, but after I close the function, this variable can't be identified. My question is how can I get the ressource variable and use its data to create this gantt chart?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transport-gantt',
  templateUrl: './transport-gantt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transport-gantt.component.css']
})
export class TransportGanttComponent implements OnInit {
  public gantdata: object[];
  public taskfield: object;
  public timelineSettings: object;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5002');

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
      let ressource: any;
      ressource = JSON.parse(evt.data);
      console.log(ressource);
    };
    let i = 0;
    let BreakException = {};
    try {
     Object.keys(ressource).forEach(key => {
       i++;
       if (i >= 1589) {
         const tab = ressource[key];
         this.gantdata.push({
          TaskName: tab[6],
          StartDate: tab[2],
          EndDate: tab[5]});
       }

       if (i == 1626 ) { throw BreakException; }

     });
   } catch (e) {
if (e !== BreakException) { throw e; }
}

    this.taskfield = {
  id: 'TaskID',
  name: 'TaskName',
  startDate: 'StartDate',
  endDate: 'EndDate',
  duration: 'Duration'
};

    this.timelineSettings = {
topTier: {
unit: 'Day',
},
bottomTier: {
  unit: 'Hour',
},
};

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the scope of `this` object. Within any function, `this` refers to a function's scope if defined with `function` keyword.

Try arrow function (`=>`) which is supported in ES6 and above

```
ws.onmessage = (evt) => {
   ......
}
```

Comment: I tried the following code with arrow function but I still don't get any data displayed in the gantt chart;

Answer (score 0):

If the console logging statement in your "ws.onmessage" function doesn't log what you expect, or never gets invoked at all, then either the WebSocket server isn't sending what you expect, or your usage of the JavaScript WebSocket API should be suspect.

Assuming that it's the latter, I suggest that instead of writing WebSocket code directly, you use a higher-level library that handles the pesky details for you.

I have found that the RxJS library, which is already present in your Angular project, has a very nice wrapper for WebSockets.

For simply listening for inbound messages, the example from the [RxJS documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) is as follows:

```
import { webSocket } from "rxjs/webSocket";
const subject = webSocket("ws://localhost:8081");

subject.subscribe(
   msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg), // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
   err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
   () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
 );
```

It really couldn't be any easier than that...